# Запросы через proxy python

Tags: python, proxy, tor, socks5

Всем привет, есть сайт, при неудачных запросах он выдаёт капчу. Подскажите пожалуйста, как делать запросы меняя каждый раз ip. Если знаете другой способ обойти блокировку, говорите.
ВАЖНО: ошибки неотъемлемая часть работы программы, их игнорировать нельзя.
Спасибо.